# Aspose-Cells (Java) connect two shapes

Tags: java, excel, aspose-cells

It is possible to connect two shapes with a connector shape? I know how to create shapes:

```
private static void createShapes(Worksheet worksheet) {
    Shape rectangle1 = worksheet.getShapes().addAutoShape(AutoShapeType.RECTANGLE, 3, 2, 3, 0, 12, 52);
    Shape rectangle2 = worksheet.getShapes().addAutoShape(AutoShapeType.RECTANGLE, 4, 2, 5, 0, 12, 52);

    Shape connector = worksheet.getShapes().addAutoShape(AutoShapeType.BENT_CONNECTOR_4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 12, 26);
    // connect rectangle1 and rectangle2 with connector
}
```

But how can I connect the shapes with the connector?

Here is an example of how I would like it to look:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to connect the shapes or create new ones here?  The title and description are contradictory.  Also do you want the two shapes to just touch each other or overlap?  How have you tried to connect the shapes so far?  This might help people to answer your question. I did not down-vote your question.

Comment: I want to connect the shapes with the connector shape. It should look like [link](http://www.edrawsoft.com/images/illustration/connect_shape_step2.png). I have not tried to connect the shapes because I do not know how.